# How do I get VNC to do fullscreen on 2 of 3 monitors

Tags: vnc

At work, I has a schmansy setup where I connect to two nice monitors via USB3. When using these, my laptop screen can also be active.

RealVNC hsa the use all monitors option. What I really want is the "use just these two monitors" option.

Fullscreen insists on centering across all three, which isn't really workable.

Is there a windows vnc client that provides the option to fullscreen only certain monitors?

Answer (score 0):

In laptop power options, set closing laptop lid to do nothing, then launch VNC in full screen mode, so that it spans the 3 monitors, then close laptop lid, and VNC should reconfigure fullscreen across remaining 2 monitors. Then reopen laptop lid, et voila, you should have separate use of your laptop screen, while using VNC fullscreen on your other 2 screens.

Answer (score 0):

I used this trick on Windows 10 with realVNC (not exactly full screen though):

1. When creating the VNC server, set the vertical resolution to be 30px less
   (say, use 1600x570 instead of 1600x600)
2. In VNC viewer, set to scale to window size
3. Move the VNC viewer window such that its right edge aligns with the right edge of the second screen
4. Move the mouse cursor above the title bar till it appears as arrows and double click